# SQL query for selecting all entries from the user with the most entries

Tags: sql

I am making a suggestions application in relation to school.

I have a table with users and a table with suggestions that share the key userId.

Every suggestions has the unique key of sugId and a duplicateable userId.

How can I select all the entries from the user with the most entries?

Comment: What have you tried? and which of `sql` vendor?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue with a small hack.

```sql
select * from suggestions
where userId = (
  select userId from suggestions
  group by userId
  order by count(sugId) desc limit 1
)
order by TimeStamp asc;
```

Just posting it here in case it is needed.

**edit
sugId had to be userId

Comment: That's an incorrect query according to your description since it returns one row only, even if multiple users with the same amount of suggestions appear.

Comment: Per the task we were only supposed to return one row and it is still a hack. Better solutions exist but haven't been posted.